# How are the values of val1, val2, val3, val4 calculated?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

```
int main(){
   int a = 1, b = 0, c = 1, val1, val2, val3, val4;
   val1 = a || b || c;
   val2 = a && b && c;
   val3 = a || b && c;
   val4 = a && b || c;

   cout<< val1 << val2 << val3 << val4;
   return 0;
}
```

How are the values of val1 to val4 calculated?

Comment: The meaning and use of these operators will have been covered early in any non-fraudulent C++ programming text.

Comment: What do *you* think? Why do you think that? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val1  =  a || b || c  =  (1 or 0) or 1    =  1 or 1   =  1
val2  =  a && b && c  =  (1 and 0) and 1  =  0 and 1  =  0
val3  =  a || b && c  =  1 or (0 and 1)   =  1 or 0   =  1
val4  =  a && b || c  =  (1 and 0) or 1   =  0 or 1   =  1
```

The `or` operation, `||`, is 1 when either side is 1 or both sides are 1.

The `and` operation, `&&`, is 1 only when *both* sides are 1.

The `and` operation always takes precedence (is calculated before `or` operations) assuming there are no parenthesis.

If all operators are of the same precedence, they are calculated from left to right.

C++ uses [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for `&&` and `||` meaning, not all steps are necessary to evaluate (just like if you multiply by 0 in a series of multiplications, you know the result is 0 without performing every calculation).

This would mean for `val2`, since `a && b` evaluates to 0, it doesn't bother to evaluate `c`. Since only `&&` operations follow, the right-hand side must evaluate to 0.

The same applies for `val3` with the `||` operator. Since `a` evaluates to 1, it doesn't bother to evaluate `b && c`. Since if any one term is 1 (in this case, `a`), the right-hand side must evaluate to 1.

Involving short-circuit evaluation, the calculations performed would be like this:

```
val1  =  a || b || c  =  1 or ...         =  1
val2  =  a && b && c  =  1 and 0 and ...  =  0
val3  =  a || b && c  =  1 or ...         =  1
val4  =  a && b || c  =  1 and 0 or 1     =  0 or 1  =  1
```

To see short-circuit evaluation in action, you can write a program that prints while evaluating variables like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int print(int x) {
  cout << x;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  int a = 1, b = 0, c = 1, val1, val2, val3, val4;

  val1 = print(a) || print(b) || print(c);
  cout << endl;

  val2 = print(a) && print(b) && print(c);
  cout << endl;

  val3 = print(a) || print(b) && print(c);
  cout << endl;

  val4 = print(a) && print(b) || print(c);
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
1
10
1
101
```

Comment: You miss the short-circuit nature of the operators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point, I've added in a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators precedence

```
    !       High
    &&   Medium
    ||      Low
```

Here is the calculation

```
   val1 = a || b || c; => 1 || 0 || 1 => 1 || 1 => 1

   val2 = a && b && c; => 1 && 0 && 1 => 0 && 1 => 0

   val3 = a || b && c;  => 1 || 0 && 1 => 1 || 0 =>1

   val4 = a && b || c; => 1 && 0 || 1 => 0 || 1 => 1
```